# Agenda de contactos en c++

Tags: c++

Necesito simular una agenda de contactos que almacene nombre,edad,apodo,numero telefonico y peso. 
Al introducir la edad el programa se salta la parte del programa para introducir el apodo, estoy utilizando getline para que el usuario pueda introducir nombres y apodos con espacios.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
int main() {

string nombre[5];
int edad[5];
string apodo[5];
long long numero[5];
double peso[5];

cout << "Por favor ingrese la siguiente informacion de el contacto: \n";
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
cout<<"CONTACTO NUMERO"<<i+1<<"\n";

cout<<"Nombre: ";
getline(cin, nombre[i]);

cout<<"Edad: ";
cin>>edad[i];

cout<<"Apodo: ";
getline(cin, apodo[i]);


cout<<"Numero: ";
cin>>numero[i];

cout<<("Peso: ");
cin>>peso[i];
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede porque el buffer se llena de datos y por ende toma lo que hay en el buffer como si escribieras en consola, lo que debes hacer es utilizar `cin.ignore()` antes del `cin` de la parte que te falle, esta función limpia el buffer

Comment: Me sirvio la solucion, investigare mas sobre ese problema del buffer, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Además de usar `cin.ignore()` como se te ha aconsejado, hay un detalle que te puede eliminar también algún dolor de cabeza. En lugar de `getline(cin, variable)` utiliza `getline (cin>>ws, variable)`. Lo que vas a conseguir con esto es que no se tomen espacios en blanco antes del nombre, cosa que puede ocurrir en algunas ocasiones. Es solo un consejo.

¿Otra cosa, en vez de tanto array "suelto", ¿por qué no usas una **estructura** con `struct`?

Tu código quedaría:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
int main() {
struct Persona{
  string nombre;
  int edad;
  string apodo;
  long numero;
  double peso;
}; //OJO aquí al punto y coma, a diferencia de las funciones, aquí hay que ponerlo

Persona personas[5];

cout << "Por favor ingrese la siguiente informacion de el contacto: \n";
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

cout<<"CONTACTO NUMERO"<<i+1<<"\n";

cout<<"Nombre: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin>>ws, personas[i].nombre);

cout<<"Edad: ";
cin>>personas[i].edad;

cout<<"Apodo: ";
getline(cin>>ws, personas[i].apodo);


cout<<"Numero: ";
cin>>personas[i].numero;

cout<<("Peso: ");
cin>>personas[i].peso;
}

return 0;
}
```

Esto puede servirte: https://www.zator.com/Cpp/E4_5_1.htm

Finalmente, edito, para incluir librerías que no has hecho tú, en vez de comillas utiliza <>. Por ejemplo, `#include <string>` en lugar de `#include "string"`.

Un saludo.